# How do I simplify operations on sets?

Tags: sets

How would I use Mathematica to simplify:

> S'∩(S∪T')'

The answer is S'∩T

Edit: S' means Complement of S.

Thanks! Solved with:

> BooleanConvert[! S && ! (S || ! T)]

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, solved it with BooleanConvert[! S \[And] ! (S \[Or] ! T)]

Comment: I moved my comment to the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is full justified from math perspective but using logic you can do:

```
BooleanConvert[! S \[And] ! (S \[Or] ! T)]
```